# How to connect a java client to SignalR Hub using only websockets?

Tags: java, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub, java-websocket

I need to access a websocket server that runs with SignalR Hub, from my Java desktop application.

- There is [a library](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client) that does exactly that, but it's dead. There are lots of issues and pull requests and it hasn't been updated since 2015.
- I also found [another library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089031/java-client-to-connect-to-signalr) but, as far as I can tell, it's only for Android projects.
- I found [a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260103/can-a-client-connect-directly-to-signalr-using-only-websockets) that says it's possible to talk directly to the SignalR server (standard websocket calls) with some workarounds, but the given link is dead.

When I tried to access the server directly with websocket, the HTTP handshaking fails (I get HTTP 200 instead of 101).

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will not be able to connect to SignalR 2.x with just bare webSocket. The reason for that is that starting the connection requires a few HTTP requests which have to be sent with in a specific order and contain specific content. I described the SignalR protocol in a [blog post](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/). After reading this post you will understand why dedicated client for SignalR 2.x existed.

Having said that - the new version of [SignalR for ASP.NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/) no longer has this protocol and requirements and it is possible to connect to the server with just bare websockets. I created a demo a while ago showing how to do this - you can find details [here](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2017/01/15/signalr-core-part-23-asp-net-sockets/). I also [started working](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples/tree/pawelka/ticker-ws) on an example for the hubs layer but need to finish it.

Comment: Your sample repo doesn't seem to have an example of connecting to SignalR using websockets - perhaps you've changed this since?

Comment: There is a social weather sample that uses just webSockets: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/dev/samples/SocialWeather/wwwroot/index.html#L70-L100. It is actually more than that - you can read the entire story here: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2017/01/15/signalr-core-part-23-asp-net-sockets/

Comment: The URL is dead, and the server at https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/tree/master/samples/SocialWeather doesn't use SignalR at all. (And the repo is archived and read-only.)

Comment: Folow-up: the WebSocket->SignalR example is at https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples/tree/pawelka/ticker-ws/StockTickR/StockTickRApp .

Comment: @Pawel And there is no possibility to check when a user lost internet connection by timeout. Again. Right?